# erro HTTP 500 no Ajax do Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal

Há dias o servidor fez um *reboot* não programado e desde então ao tentar editar qualquer dado no Drupal, o erro abaixo é retornado.

O erro acontece quando clico no botão *"Customize this page"*.

Já procurei no Google uma solução, mas já fiquei sem opções.
O que poderá ser?

> Ocorreu um erro HTTP no Ajax.
>
> Código de Resultado HTTP: 500
>
> Segue informação para depuração.
>
> Caminho: /panels/ajax/ipe/save_form/panel_context%3Apage-homepage%3A%3Apage_homepage_panel_context_2%3A%3A%3A%3A
>
> Texto de Estado: Internal Server Error
>
> Texto de Resposta: !responsetext

Comment: o que diz o log?

Comment: @BrunoRozendo qual log? O único log que tenho é o alert que aparece no browser com a mensagem que postei acima. Conheço pouco de drupal, por isso pergunto, qual log se refere? Obrigado.

Comment: Procure pelo Log do apache. Você está rodando o drupal no windows ou linux?

Comment: @BrunoRozendo Linux, mas não tenho acesso ao log do apache, não sou administrador.

Comment: se já está num hospedagam web provavelmente você tem acesso ao logo via ftp, geralmente fica no no root: `/log` ou algo to tipo, dá uma vasculhada, para vêr o que encontra

Comment: @BrunoRozendo sim, geralmente temos o errolog mas não o encontro em lado nenhum... asism fica dificil saber qual o problema :(

Comment: Entra em contato com servidor e diz que você precisa do log, pq sem ele não tem como identificar o problema

Comment: @BrunoRozendo acabei por ter acesso via FTP e ao cpanel, não encontrei errolog em nenhum local... poderá ser alguma configuração no cpanel, drupal ou htacess para que nenhum errolog seja gerado? Eu alterei a versão do php e funcionou, portanto dever ser mesmo um problema no php e deve existir um errolog em algum lado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido.
Devido a uma actualização no servidor, por algum motivo, a versão do php foi alterada para 5.4.
Voltei a seleccionar a versão 5.3 e voltou a funcionar.
Com certeza foi incompatibilidade de versões.